# Plotting multiple points instead of just one in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, tweepy, matplotlib-basemap

Not sure why it's not producing all of their points. Here is my code:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

Comment: Oh no, Justin Bieber has invaded StackOverflow! D:

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal non-working example, using some hardcoded data, so we can see the structure of your data and we don't need to get the data ourselves using tweepy?

Comment: @sebix it pulls up a map with just one plot on it because it pulls the coordinates of the latitude and longitude

Comment: @sebix I added more information to the post. Hopefully that clarifies it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just cache the data and then plot them all in the end:

```
class listener(StreamListener):
    x = []
    y = []

    def on_status(self, status):

        if status.coordinates:
            print status.coordinates
            coords  = status.coordinates
            latitude = coords['coordinates'][0]
            longitude = coords['coordinates'][1]
            xt,yt = m(latitude, longitude)
            self.x.append(xt)
            self.y.append(yt)

            return True
    def plotAll(self):
        m.plot(self.x, self.y, 'ro', markersize=20, alpha=.5)

Plotter = listener()
try:
    auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
    auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
    twitterStream = Stream(auth, Plotter)
    twitterStream.filter(track=["justin", "bieber"])
    Plotter.plotAll()
except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
    plt.show()
```

Can't test it with your specific conditions and `OAuthHandler`, but it worked here without it.